# Gitlab-CI build fails with docker

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm just trying to get familiar with Gitlab and trying to see how it can be useful for my needs. I wrote a simple javascript program and an unit test for it in TapeJS.

`isAnagram.js`

```
module.exports = function(string1, string2){

if (string1.length != string2.length){
    return false
}

string1 = string1.replace(/[\s\W]+/g, '');
string2 = string2.replace(/[\s\W]+/g, '');

string1 = string1.toLowerCase().split('').sort();
string2 = string2.toLowerCase().split('').sort();

if(string1.toString() == string2.toString()){
    return true
} else {
    return false
}
}
```

`test.js`

```
var test = require('tape').test,
isA = require('./isAnagram');

test('Is it an Anagram? ', function(t){
    var actual = isA('iceman', 'cinema');
    var expected = true;
    t.equal(actual, expected);
    t.end();
});
```

Gitlab runner file `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`:

```
    concurrent = 1
    check_interval = 0

    [[runners]]
      name = "Test runner"
      url = "http://172.16.205.131/ci"
      token = "043e80c412bd5bb73d2ef98d66117e"
      executor = "docker"
      [runners.docker]
        tls_verify = false
        image = "ubuntu:latest"
        privileged = false
        disable_cache = false
        volumes = ["/cache"]
      [runners.cache]
```

Test results:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.5.3 (fb49c47)
Using Docker executor with image ubuntu:latest ...
Pulling docker image ubuntu:latest ...
Running on runner-043e80c4-project-2-concurrent-0 via iwinks...
Fetching changes...
Checking out 872868f4 as master...
fatal: reference is not a tree: 872868f4555bfe7429724e1569c9a4ef142510f2
ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong and don't understand what the problem exactly is and what does "reference is not a tree" mean?

Comment: The runner is checking out code using Git which is throwing an error. See [other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22reference+is+not+a+tree%22). Maybe they will push you in the right direction.

Comment: May be you do `git push` with `--force` after that commit? In that case hash of commit changes.